# How do I ignore inputs that don't have data in update method

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a form to update user data name and email and username. The question is if user want to update only user, how do I keep same email and name or change only name in my case the validation required all inputs this is my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $username )
{
    if($username != Auth::user()->username){
        return abort('401');
    }

    $request->validate([

        'name' => 'min:10|max:50|required',
        'username' => 'unique:users|max:30|min:3|required',
        'email' => 'email|unique:users|max:200|required',

    ]);
    $checkuserindb = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);

    $checkuserindb->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'username' => $request->username,
        'email' => $request->email
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('userProfile', $request->username)->with('message', 'your account has been updated!');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your input field just add the actual value from database like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{$user->name}}">
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{$user->username}}">
<input type="email" name="email" value="{{$user->email}}">
```

Also use 'sometimes' rule and update any of the fields you want:

```
'name'     => 'min:10|max:50|sometimes',
'username' => 'unique:users|max:30|min:3|sometimes',
'email'    => 'email|unique:users|max:200|sometimes',
```

Comment: it's finally worked but i add some stuff into validate ruls                                                          
               ` $attributes = $request->validate([
            'name'     => 'min:10|max:50|sometimes',
            'username' => 'sometimes|max:30|min:3|string|unique:users,username,' . $checkuserindb->id,
            'email'    => 'sometimes|email|unique:users,email,'.$checkuserindb->id,
        ]); `